# Change turtle size keeping lower point position constant

Tags: netlogo

I have distributed turtles on the world having size `x` and I wish to increase their size to `y` but the I want to keep their location of their lower further point same (Check figure below). How can one accomplish this?

EDIT:
I wished to write a procedure that could be applicable for all turtle heading, that is if the turtle is heading 0 or 90 or 45. Direct math in such case could be complicated.
[image: Figure]

Comment: Surely you can figure out the math on this by yourself?

Comment: What shape is the turtle? If it's circular, then it doesn't matter what the heading is. If it isn't circular, then I guess you've got some math to do. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Consider a box whose sides are made up of turtles. In such a case, the heading would matter. You will need to write a separate code for each side(4 sides) using simple maths. I was looking for generalized procedure. But if I set heading to all sides at start, a simple math procedure could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Seth said, this should be relatively straight forward math. If you don't want to do the math, though, and this is only for visual purposes, you could make a new turtle shape, where the "bottom" of the shape is actually at the center. Then, when turning, it will like the turtle is turning around their bottom. When changing size, again, the "bottom" will stay in the same place.

Comment: My answer handles exactly the case you describe. The math is also pretty straight forward for it as well.

Comment: I use the center of turtle for computation, so visual solution won't help